# KeyError: 'Date'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
#URL of the dataset
path2="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XDs3pqZJK7_9Tx28czANgDVEJ_pB_ea8/view?usp=sharing"
#reading the csv file
data2 = pd.read_csv(path2)
#sorting the dataset with respect to Date.
data2 = data2.sort_values('Date')
#Let's have a sneek peek of the dataset.
data2.head()
```

Im trying to read and sort a .csv file and this throws up the error .

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a50f2c66a46c> in <module>
      4 data2 = pd.read_csv(path2)
      5 #sorting the dataset with respect to Date.
----> 6 data2 = data2.sort_values('Date')
      7 #Let's have a sneek peek of the dataset.
      8 data2.head()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1777             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1778         else:
-> 1779             raise KeyError(key)
   1780 
   1781         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Date'
```

what to do ?

I cant figure out what to do

---

Update !

I removed the 'data2-data2.sort_values('Date') and it ran successfully but the output I received is this

[is my csv file incorrect here ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fiXN.png)

[this is the actual file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMUVF.png)

Comment: Debug the value of `data2`. What columns does it have?

Comment: You could delete the line `data2 = data2.sort_values('Date')`.

Comment: By default, `pd.read_csv()` uses the first column as the index; use `index_col=False` to disable this and make it a data column.

Comment: Columns of the file are as follows : Date , open ,high ,low ,close ,adj close , volume

Comment: When you fetch that URL, you get a web page,, not a CSV.  Try using `requests` to fetch the CSV file.  If you start from the CSV, then it imports properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify url and then try to fetch data.
What you trying to fetch results in getting HTML source code. And not the csv content. Try like -

```
path2="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XDs3pqZJK7_9Tx28czANgDVEJ_pB_ea8/edit"
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + path2.split('/')[-2]
#reading the csv file
data2 = pd.read_csv(url)
#sorting the dataset with respect to Date.
data2 = data2.sort_values('Date')
#Let's have a sneek peek of the dataset.
data2.head()
```